# Branch.io links not tracking clicks after custom subdomain setup

Tags: branch.io

**BACKGROUND**

- I have an app that was set up using a default branch domain (ex: my.app.link).
- Links were created using my.app.link.  Many of these links needed to mirror existing links I have in production (with another linking service that we are migrating off of) that use a format not supported in Branch.io, so I had to work around the issue by using a '-' in place of '.' in the link's path.  This is a solution recommended by Branch with the assurance that the '.' would be translated to a '-' on the backend at Branch.io (this appears to work fine).
- I recently had a custom subdomain CNAMEd over to custom.bnc.lt (ex: myapp.mydomain.com).
- The link settings in the Branch.io dashboard have been updated to use the custom subdomain (change is valid: "Domain is correctly set up and SSL is working.").

**ISSUES**

1. All pre-existing quick links still have the old default domain, no clicks register even though they 'work' with the new subdomain.
2. Duplicating one of these links picks up the new subdomain, but the url that gets created is http, not https (which is the default for any other link we created and there doesn't seem to be a way to choose one protocol or the other, nor can it be updated in the dashboard).  This also seems to be causing link clicks to not track in the dashboard.
3. The fact that we mirrored links from another platform using a workaround (replacing '.' for a '-'), also seems to cause link clicks to not track in the dashboard.

**QUESTIONS**

How does Branch.io handle link clicks for a quick link that has been set up for an app using a custom subdomain?  Does the configured link need to match 1:1 to the link that is clicked on the device?

How can I fix the original links, especially if I can't duplicate them (to pick up the custom subdomain) in a way that gives me a 1:1 match to the previous link I created (since the new link is http and the others are https, as would be distributed in a live/production environment)?

Why isn't Branch tracking link clicks for the x.y.z links that I set up as x-y-z?  This aliasing works fine, and seemed to be tracking clicks fine in test.

Answer (score 1):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

**1. How does Branch.io handle link clicks for a quick link that has been set up for an app using a custom subdomain?**

A: For all Branch links, every time a Branch link is clicked the click is is registered by Branch. Using a custom domain (if configured properly) should not cause any problems in registering clicks on the Branch dashboard neither should using Quick links cause any issues. Also Branch links with either schemes http:// or https:// register link clicks. Having Branch links with http:// scheme should not cause any issues with registering link clicks

**2.All pre-existing quick links still have the old default domain**

A: The old links created on the app.link will not be updated with your custom domain. If you wish to use links with your link domain, you can create new links with the same link parameters. (PS: both links on the old app.link domain and links on your custom domain should work as before if you still have your App configured to support the app.link domain links.)

**3. Duplicating one of these links picks up the new subdomain, but the url that gets created is http, not https**

A: At present, the Branch API creates Branch links for custom domains with the 'http://'scheme. This is because we are not sure if custom domains have the SSL certificate and creating links with the https:// scheme would break for such domains. Hence by default, all custom domain links are created using the http:// scheme. There is no direct way to create links using the https:// scheme using the Branch API, the only way you can do it is by manually changing the scheme from 'http' to 'https://'.

**4. Why isn't Branch tracking link clicks for the x.y.z links that I set up as x-y-z? This aliasing works fine, and seemed to be tracking clicks fine in test.**

I believe, the issue here has nothing to do with your custom domain but is maybe related to a key mismatch. You mention that the link clicks were tracked in the test version of the App, which leads me to believe that your app is still using the Branch key from the test version (key format: key_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX). Please ensure that your App is using the correct key. The simple test for this: When you click on the Branch link, you get the link parameters in your app and the link parameters contain `+clicked_branch_link:true`. If so, the link click will be tracked on Branch's end.

If you still continue to face issues, you could write to `integrations@branch.io` and our team would be more than happy to help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Would the branch key matter if we've opted not to integrate with the SDK yet?  Without the SDK it seems that Branch.io will track link clicks for an exact match between the link set up in the dashboard and the link that was clicked (protocol, domain, link/path).  This appears to be even down to the char case for the link (ex: X.y.z and x.y.z do not produce a click event).

Comment: @dev-null I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Could you explain you test plan in detail please. Also, what is the link behavior is you do not have the SDK integrated.

Comment: We have existing links that we are using with another provider that contain '.' (ex: Ab.c.d).  Branch.io does not allow the '.' character when creating links in the dashboard.  Branch.io informed us that we could still use our old links, but would need to set them up with a '-' instead of the '.' and that the backend would handle the '.' on the referrer as a '-' thus allowing us to keep our old links as-is (until we had the time to clean them up with pretty short urls like 'invite' or 'download').

Comment: It all worked fine when we tried it out, but I am now noticing that the link clicks do not track unless the link that was clicked was a 100% match to the one that we set up in Branch.io.  So, the workaround to keep our old Ab.c.d links by setting up Ab-c-d links in Branch.io still works, but we don't see any clicks tracking in the dashboard.